# Unsorted custom intersection

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of complex numbers, `list1` and `list2`, sorted by decreasing imaginary part. `list2` is strictly longer than `list1`.

Most numbers of `list1` will be different than those in `list2`, but some will be close.

I want to find the intersection of these lists, where two complex numbers are considered equal if they differ in absolute value by at most `10^-n`.

The built-in way to do this would be

```
intersection = Intersection[list1,list2,SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]<10^-4&)];
```

However the intersection I want is different from this:

- The order should stay fixed
- Duplicates within one list should not be removed
- By default the intersection should be taken from `list1`, with the option of also giving a second list which is the intersection with elements taken from `list2`.
- This second intersection should differ from the first only in the order `10^-n` differences in the elements, not in length or ordering.

A simple but slow way of doing this would be:

```
intersection1 = Select[list1,Min@Abs[#-list2]<10^-4&];
intersection2 = Function[el1,MinimalBy[list2,Abs[#-el1]&][[1]]]/@intersection1;
```

Note that if we did the `intersection2` the same way as `intersection1`, it would likely contain more elements, as `list2` is longer than `list1`, so `list2` may contain several points close to one point in `intersection1`.

There must be a more elegant and quick way though, at the very least this is doing the work twice.

Typical list lengths are from 100 to 1000 elements, around 10.000 at the very max, so speed is important but not critical, I'm mostly just curious how to do this properly in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) for determining `intersection1`. Here is some sample data:

```
SeedRandom[3];
list1=RandomComplex[1+I, 10^3];
list2=RandomComplex[1+I, 10^4];
```

Create the [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) function:

```
nf = Nearest[list1 -> {"Element", "Distance"}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000092, Null}

Apply the nearest function to the second list, and select the elements that are close:

```
Cases[nf[list2], {{p_, d_}} /; d < 10^-4 :> p] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.047424, {0.68503 + 0.864287 I}}

Compare to your function:

```
intersection1 = Select[list1, Min@Abs[#-list2]<10^-4&] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.165176, {0.68503 + 0.864287 I}}

Comment: Thanks, that speeds it up. One issue I have with it is that this form of Nearest with -> {"Element", "Distance"} was only added recently, and I want my code to be compatible as far back as possible. More importantly it should be possible to get intersection2 at almost no cost relative to only intersection 1, it seems Nearest almost has this functionality built in, but not quite.